# Is there an official Star Trek Day?

Tags: star-trek

All good Star Wars fans know that the 4th of May is Star Wars day, so my question is: **Is there an equivalent day for Star Trek?**  If so, *when is it?*

Comment: @Pureferret Did you really mean to protect this question and put a mod-banner on it, a mere 6 minutes after it was posted, and before *any* answers (let alone low-quality ones) had come in? Or did you click on the wrong question or something?

Comment: Curious that this should attract a downvote!

Comment: @TheDoc : Curious, indeed.  Someone on this site has made it his or her life's mission to slowly downvote anything and everything Star Trek.

Comment: @TheDoc I upvoted (and would have posted an answer). Wondering if we should assume Pureferret made a mistake and unprotect it - but we wouldn't want to look as though we were undermining him...

Comment: The Bartlett administration couldn't get it done

Comment: Even more curious that this should attract *4* downvotes!  Could someone please explain what is wrong with this question possibly?  I am at quite a loss to explain this occurrence!

Comment: My logic is partly based on previous experience of these sorts of questions which are very accessible to poor quality opinion based answers, as well as being one of our most popular topics. If the consensus is to unprotect it,  then I can.

Comment: @Pureferret Given your experience in these matters I think it probably is a wise idea to maintain the protection of the question

Comment: May 4th for Star Wars is not 'official.' Every May when I hear or read this phrase, I respond, "The first Star Wars was released on May 25th, 1977" and "why are you lisping?"

Comment: Disney and StarWars.com have [officially acknowledged May 4th being Star Wars Day](http://www.starwars.com/may-the-4th)

Comment: [multiple times](http://www.starwars.com/video/may-the-4th-be-with-you-how-fans-celebrate-star-wars-day), [actually](http://www.starwars.com/video/star-wars-day-attack-ad-say-no-to-may-the-4th).

Comment: @TheDoc : See updates to my answer. :-)

Comment: @Praxis seen and noted - I think your's is the better answer now although commendable efforts from Kerr!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## "Star Trek Day" is the 8th of September.

[image]

The first episode of *The Original Series* aired on **8 September 1966**.  The graphic above is from an advertisement that Oreo Cookies made to celebrate Star Trek  Day, with approval from CBS (which owns the Star Trek television series).

Google has also traditionally done its special Star Trek Google Doodles on the 8th of September:

[image]
[image]

Many Star Trek web sites / fan sites / fanzines agree, treating the 8th of September as a *special day* (one "worthy of song", as the Klingons might say).

Examples:

- [TrekNews.net — *Star Trek* Celebrates 49 Years](http://www.treknews.net/2015/09/08/star-trek-celebrates-49-years/)
- [Star Trek New Voyages — September 8, 2015: Happy 49th Birthday *Star Trek*!](http://www.startreknewvoyages.com/2013/09/05/happy-47th-birthday-star-trek-september-6-in-canada-september-8-in-the-u-s/)

Furthermore, the [UFStarfleet group](http://www.ufstarfleet.org/wiki/index.php?title=United_Federation_Starfleet) (one of the major Star Trek fan groups) maintains that September 8 is **"Star Trek Day"**:

> EVENT: Star Trek Day
>
> DATE: September 8
>
> DESCRIPTION: Celebration commemorating the premiere of Star Trek on television in 1966. **Celebrated across the Internet.**

([Source](http://www.ufstarfleet.org/wiki/index.php?title=Star_Trek_Holidays))

Also, [here](http://trekmovie.com/2012/09/08/oreo-is-captain-kirk-to-milks-spock-on-star-trek-day/), *Trek Movie* declares September 8 to be Star Trek Day.

Also, this Facebook group:

- [Facebook — September 8, National Star Trek Day](https://www.facebook.com/National-Star-Trek-Day-1575020492755625/)

Of course, 8 September 2016 will be a particularly important day of celebration for Star Trek fans worldwide, given that it is will be the 50th anniversary of the franchise.

Interestingly, *Star Trek* was first seen in Canada, on the 6th of September — two days before the US got to see it, as the Star Trek New Voyages article points out.

There is also ["First Contact Day"](http://www.startrek.com/article/have-a-great-first-contact-day), which is the **5th of April**, but this is more in-universe than out-of-universe (and I interpreted the question as being out-of-universe).

Comment: I concede. Good argument, well made.

Comment: @KerrAvon : Yours were good, too!  As Trek fans, we should celebrate *both*. ;-)

Comment: The more Star Trek the better ^ !

Answer (score 29):

In universe, one of the most celebrated days for humans is April 5 **"First Contact Day"** celebrated to honor both Zefram Cochrane's first warp 1 flight of the Phoenix and first open contact between Humans and Vulcans on that date in 2063 in Bozeman, Montana.

This date has been adopted by many fans and is the closest equivalent to Star Wars' May the 4th.

EDIT to provide Doc with requested evidence:

**LINKS**

http://www.fcd2016.com/

https://www.facebook.com/StarTrekDay/

http://www.startrek.com/article/have-a-great-first-contact-day

**SNIPS**

[image: Message from StarTrek.com staff]

[image: The Mary Sue celebrate...]

Comment: There's also a pleasing symmetry to celebrating one franchise on 5/4 and the other franchise on 4/5...

Comment: The one reason I'm leaning towards @Praxis' answer currently is there is evidence in that answer which indicates that fans celebrate that day. If you were to provide evidence that supports your assertion that fans do indeed celebrate this date I think that would push me towards your answer

Comment: @Micah: Indeed! We can choose 5/4 if we're into Star Trek, and 4/5 if we're into Star Wars, which is great!